# Obtain function that models strange oscillating data points

Tags: regression, interpolation

I've collected some interesting data from a fairly complex Python program I've written and I'm curious to figure out the mathematics behind it; or, at least, the empirical mathematics.  Analyzing the program itself is far beyond my skills, so I'm wondering if there's a specific technique that may be helpful for fitting a curve to the observed data.  The plot essentially looks like this (both X and Y are discrete, and ignore the sudden truncation at the end (x should continue indefinitely)):

[image]

So it kind of looks like the non-negative part of a sine wave whose period increases as $x$ does, and whose amplitude is decreasing.  What techniques do you know to fit a function to data like this?  If you know these techniques, can you apply it to this data?  I will provide it in CSV format here for those who are interested:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gMwBEZiisSJpQpaYcHjNIqvyKAtTSgz5

Comment: Could you tell us what the axes represent?  What is being plotted?

Comment: The number of occurrences of an event out of 1000 given the value of X is known.  The event itself is pretty complicated to explain.

Comment: The pattern is clear: it is close to a periodic symmetric triangular wave as a function of $\log_3(X)$: that is, it repeats every time you triple the value of $X.$  (The response is remarkably homoscedastic, despite the appearances.)  That should give you some clues concerning what aspect(s) of your program are determining this behavior.